# How each and individually differ as an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

> 1. The legs of the chair are **individually** joined to the seat by screws.
> 2. The legs of the chair are **each** joined to the seat by screws.

I would like to know if there is any difference between the two sentences above I created. I think the first sentence means each leg is joined by one or more screws while the second means each leg is joined by two or more screws, but I am not sure it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they are quite different, and you could even use *both* in your example sentence:

> *Each* chair leg is *individually* joined to the seat by screws.

"Each" is used to refer to multiple things, which are regarded and identified separately. It can group those individual things together, for example, "*each day I go to work*" is referring to *every* day that you go to work. Yet, it is different from "every", because a person may work 5 days out of 7, so saying "each day" rather than "every day" refers to all the specific calendar days that you personally work.

"Individually" means *one by one* or *separately*, so rather than group things together, this is used to break them up again.

In my example that uses both words, "each refers to *all* the legs of the chair, and "individually" refers to the fact they are fastened to the base separately.